# Is user logged in facebook is on my page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there posibility, to check, that user on my www is logged in this time in to facebook and get his/her uid number?

I try to use FB.getLoginStatus but I get nothing special ;/

Comment: Can you post your code example? Or link to a live example?

Comment: live example: http://bskone.com/fb/testtest/

Answer (score 0):

You need to FB.init() with oauth: true and use response.authSession.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Abby

Comment: ok, but still I cannot get uid if user did not authorized app :-(

Comment: No, you can't take information about a user without their permission.